# Best way to bind Windows Forms properties to ApplicationSettings in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

In a desktop application needing some serious re-factoring, I have several chunks of code that look like this:

```
private void LoadSettings()
{
    WindowState = Properties.Settings.Default.WindowState;
    Location = Properties.Settings.Default.WindowLocation;
    ...
}

private void SaveSettings()
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.WindowState = WindowState;
    Properties.Settings.Default.WindowLocation = Location;
    ...
}
```

What's the best way to replace this? Project-imposed constraints:

- Visual Studio 2005
- C# / .NET 2.0
- Windows Forms

**Update**

For posterity, I've also found two useful tutorials: ["Windows Forms User Settings in C#"](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/UserSettings.aspx) and ["Exploring Secrets of Persistent Application Settings"](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/33944/0/page/1).

*I've asked a follow-up question about using this technique to bind a form's Size [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18585/why-cant-you-bind-the-size-of-a-windows-form-to-applicationsettings). I separated them out to help people who search for similar issues.*
­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you open your windows form in the designer, look in the properties box. The first item should be "(ApplicationSetting)". Under that is "(PropertyBinding)". That's where you'll find the option to do exactly what you want.

Comment: Could you provide more info about this?