# Best way to bind WPF properties to ApplicationSettings in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio

What is the best way to bind WPF properties to ApplicationSettings in C#?  Is there an automatic way like in a Windows Forms Application? Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18421/best-way-to-bind-windows-forms-properties-to-applicationsettings-in-c), how (and is it possible to) do you do the same thing in WPF?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

You can directly bind to the static object created by Visual Studio.

In your windows declaration add:

```
xmlns:p="clr-namespace:UserSettings.Properties"
```

where `UserSettings` is the application namespace.

Then you can add a binding to the correct setting:

```
<TextBlock Height="{Binding Source={x:Static p:Settings.Default}, 
           Path=Height, Mode=TwoWay}" ....... />
```

Now you can save the settings, per example when you close your application:

```
protected override void OnClosing(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    base.OnClosing(e); 
}
```

Comment: I was surprised that the `TwoWay` binding actually works in both ways. Nice. +1

Comment: Note to searchers out there, *TwoWay* is REQUIRED or the settings won't be saved.  Annoying to try and figure that one out.

Comment: For a slightly different syntax (and a good intro), read http://blogs.msdn.com/b/patrickdanino/archive/2008/07/23/user-settings-in-wpf.aspx

Comment: While this is a great answer to the asked question, I've found that binding is not really the right answer for the Tools/Options dialog style of editing settings; you don't want to copy the widget values to the properties until the user clicks the OK button. Using explicit code to do this in the OK click handler means the Cancel button doesn't need a handler at all provided IsCancel == true

Comment: @PeterWone to persist the settings you need to use Properties.Settings.Default.Save() from what I've read, so in your scenario at Cancel action on the property editing dialog, you would use Properties.Settings.Default.Reload() [and at OK you'd call Save]

Comment: @GeorgeBirbilis - Reload will reload *all* of the values. This will almost certainly produce side-effects for software that slavishly uses  binding everywhere.

Comment: This method only works if the settings file is marked as public access modifier. Also In order to save the value using MyApp.Properties.Settings.Default.Save(), the setting scope has to be set to User. See 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/845033/194717

Answer (score 9):

In case you are a **VB.Net** developer attempting this, the answer is a smidge different.

```
xmlns:p="clr-namespace:ThisApplication"
```

Notice the .Properties isn't there.

---

In your binding it's MySettings.Default, instead of Settings.Default - since the app.config stores it differently.

```
<TextBlock Height={Binding Source={x:Static p:MySettings.Default}, Path=Height, ...
```

After a bit of pulling out my hair, I discovered this. Hope it helps

Answer (score 7):

I like the accepted answer, I ran into a special case though.  I had my text box set as "read only" so that I can change the value of it only in the code.  I couldn't understand why the value wasn't propagated back to the Settings although I had the Mode as "TwoWay".

Then, I found this:   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger.aspx

> The default is Default, which returns the default UpdateSourceTrigger value of the target dependency property. However, the default value for most dependency properties is PropertyChanged, while **the Text property has a default value of LostFocus**.

Thus, if you have the text box with IsReadOnly="True" property, you have to add a UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged value to the Binding statement:

```
<TextBox Text={Binding Source={x:Static p:Settings.Default}, Path=myTextSetting, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged} ... />
```

Comment: best practice is to do it this way, imho.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way would be to bind to an object that exposes your application settings as properties or to include that object as a StaticResource and bind to that.

Another direction you could take is creation your own [Markup Extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747254.aspx) so you can simply use PropertyName="{ApplicationSetting SomeSettingName}". To create a custom markup extension you need to inherit [MarkupExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.markupextension.aspx) and decorate the class with a [MarkupExtensionReturnType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.markupextensionreturntypeattribute.aspx) attribute. [John Bowen](http://blogs.interknowlogy.com/johnbowen) has a [post on creating a custom MarkupExtension](http://blogs.interknowlogy.com/johnbowen/archive/2007/05/16/13445.aspx) that might make the process a little clearer.

Answer (score 3):

Kris, I'm not sure this is the best way to bind ApplicationSettings, but this is how I did it in [Witty](http://code.google.com/p/wittytwitter/).

1) Create a dependency property for the setting that you want to bind in the window/page/usercontrol/container. This is case I have an user setting to play sounds.

```
    public bool PlaySounds
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(PlaySoundsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PlaySoundsProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PlaySoundsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("PlaySounds", typeof(bool), typeof(Options),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnPlaySoundsChanged)));

    private static void OnPlaySoundsChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.PlaySounds = (bool)args.NewValue;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }
```

2) In the constructor, initialize the property value to match the application settings

```
      PlaySounds = Properties.Settings.Default.PlaySounds;
```

3) Bind the property in XAML

```
      <CheckBox Content="Play Sounds on new Tweets" x:Name="PlaySoundsCheckBox" IsChecked="{Binding Path=PlaySounds, ElementName=Window, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

You can download the full [Witty source](http://code.google.com/p/wittytwitter/) to see it in action or browse just the [code for options window](http://code.google.com/p/wittytwitter/source/browse/trunk/Witty/Witty/Options.xaml.cs).

Comment: the method by sasha (see other answer) is shorter

Comment: Uhhh, what happens when you have 100+ settings? :O

Answer (score 3):

I like to do it through the ViewModel and just do the binding as normal in the XAML

```
    public Boolean Value
    {
        get
        {
            return Settings.Default.Value;

        }
        set
        {
            Settings.Default.SomeValue= value;
            Settings.Default.Save();
            Notify("SomeValue");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think this is the best solution for most cases, because it enforces consistency. For the UI there is no difference if the value comes from the Settings or from anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Also read [this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/LearningWPFWithBabySmashConfigurationWithDataBinding.aspx) article on how it is done in BabySmash

You only need to back the Settings with DO (Like Alan's example) if you need the change notification! binding to the POCO Settings class will also work!