# Bind to a value defined in the Settings

Tags: wpf, binding, appsettings

In WPF, Can I use binding with values defined in Settings? If this is possible, please provide a sample.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

First, you need to add a custom XML namespace that will design the namespace where the settings are defined:

```
xmlns:properties="clr-namespace:TestSettings.Properties"
```

Then, in your XAML file, access the default settings instance using the following syntax:

```xml
{x:Static properties:Settings.Default}
```

So here is the final result code:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lb"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static properties:Settings.Default},
                               Path=Names}" />
```

Source: [WPF - How to bind a control to a property defined in the Settings?](http://weblogs.asp.net/thomaslebrun/archive/2009/03/26/wpf-how-to-bind-a-control-to-a-property-defined-in-the-settings.aspx)

---

*Note: As pointed out by @Daniel and @nabulke, don't forget to set **Access Modifier** of your settings file to `Public` and **Scope** to `User`*

Comment: I have found that this method only works if the settings file is marked as public access modifier. http://shortfastcode.blogspot.com/2009/12/binding-to-settings-file.html

Comment: In order to save the value using `MyApp.Properties.Settings.Default.Save()`, the setting scope has to be set to **User**.

Answer (score 32):

The solution above does work, but I find it quite verbose... you could use a custom markup extension instead, that could be used like this :

```
<ListBox x:Name="lb" ItemsSource="{my:SettingBinding Names}" />
```

Here is the code for this extension :

```
public class SettingBindingExtension : Binding
{
    public SettingBindingExtension()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    public SettingBindingExtension(string path)
        :base(path)
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    private void Initialize()
    {
        this.Source = WpfApplication1.Properties.Settings.Default;
        this.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
    }
}
```

More details here : http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2008/11/18/wpf-binding-to-application-settings-using-a-markup-extension/

Comment: This is a great extension, but unfortunately you lose Resharper intellisense. Not worth the tradeoff IMHO, though it should be noted that I am a hopeless R# fanboy :)

Comment: @OhadSchneider, indeed. I use ReSharper myself, but rarely for XAML, because I don't find it as good as in C#...

Answer (score 10):

@CSharper's answer did not work for my WPF application coded in VB.NET (not C#, unlike apparently 99.999% of other WPF applications), as I got a persistent compiler error complaining that `Settings` could not be found in the `MyApp.Properties` namespace, which would not go away even after rebuilding.

What worked instead for me, after much searching online, was to instead use the `local` XAML namespace created by default in my application's main window XAML file:

```
<Window
    <!-- Snip -->
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"
    <!-- Snip -->
><!-- Snip --></Window>
```

...and bind to my settings through it using something like the following (where `MyBooleanSetting` is a setting I defined in my project properties of type `Boolean` and scope User, with the default Friend access modifier):

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Source={x:Static local:MySettings.Default}, Path=MyBooleanSetting, Mode=TwoWay}"
          Content="This is a bound CheckBox."/>
```

To ensure the settings are actually saved, be sure to call

```
MySettings.Default.Save()
```

...somewhere in your code-behind (such as in the `Me.Closing` event for your `MainWindow.xaml.vb` file).

*(Credit to this [Visual Studio forum post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ce03cf6b-cca0-472c-b130-04a9772b7535/binding-control-properties-to-application-settings?forum=wpf) for the inspiration; see the reply by Muhammad Siddiqi.)*

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I bind the UserSettings:

Generate a dependency variable by typing `propdp` and then tab twice.

```
    public UserSettings userSettings
    {
        get { return (UserSettings)GetValue(userSettingsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(userSettingsProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty userSettingsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("userSettings", typeof(UserSettings), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(UserSettings.Default));
```

Now, you can bind `userSettings` by:

```
Value="{Binding userSettings.SomeUserSettingHere, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

And make sure you save UserSettings when you change them or on Exit by:

```
UserSettings.Default.Save();
```