# Bind c# WPF Checkbox to Application Setting and update setting

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox

In a WPF app using C#, I want to bind the default value of a `CheckBox` to the value of an Application Setting (`Properties.Settings.Default.OpenAutomatically` of type `bool`), such that when the form loads, the `CheckBox` is automatically set to the value read from the bound Application Setting.

Secondly, when the `CheckBox`'s value changes (via the user clicking on it), the `bool` Application Setting should be kept in sync (true if checked, false if unchecked).

This seems like something .NET should give you out of the box without having to write code to keep the Setting in sync when a user manipulates the UI.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845030/bind-to-a-value-defined-in-the-settings

Comment: @kenny - the question you referenced talks about binding a ListBox to a Setting, which is not a bool.  If I bind a CheckBox to bool, will the Setting automatically be updated as the value of the CheckBox changes?

Comment: I would think you can bind to a bool similarly, but I haven't tried it. Perhaps your issue is that you need to .Save() the settings somewhere else.

Comment: I don't think you'll get INotify events... if that's your concern.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference the namespace (YourNamespace.Properties.Settings) in your XAML and bind to Settings members but there will be no change notification (since the settings do not implement any type of change notification) so if you bind to it directly you will get the values stored in the Settings but you will not be able to update your settings by simply checking or unchecking the checkbox... although I'm not 100% sure that it would not be possible to achieve the updates as well using Triggers and Interactivity/Interactions to call the `Settings.Default.Save()` method...

I think you'll have to use a `ViewModel`, bind your `CheckBox` to a Property in that ViewModel and when the property changes (or a Save button is clicked) call `Settings.Default.Save()` method of your Settings from your ViewModel... that's how I do it, but again, I've never tried using Triggers in the View to call the `Save()` method because I usually have lots of settings and even if that was possible I wouldn't want all those Triggers and Method calls in my XAML anyway...