# Modifying a resource dictionary with a settings file

Tags: c#, wpf, resourcedictionary

I have a resource dictionary that contains definitions of standard colours that my application uses. At the moment these are hard coded into my resource dictionary.
I would like to get these colours from a settings file to enable the user to select their own colours.
so my question is, how can I update and modify a resource dictionary through code?

I am using WPF, C#, Visual Studio 2012 and a healthy dose of tea.

Comment: It sounds more like you want a settings file - [Using Settings in C# (Msdn)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: I think he probably wants to reference to Settings in XAML (ResourceDictionary).

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/845030/80926 if skipping the ResourceDictionary is a possibility.