# using app.config settings in xaml wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="inactivity_interval" value="10" />
  <add key="maximumHeightPopUp" value="260" />
  <add key="horizontalArrowsHeight" value="35" />
  <add key="modelsListHeight" value="100" />
</appSettings>
```

I want to use part of this settings in the xaml for example to set grid height.
Is it possible?

Comment: Check the resources provided in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3784591/2279200) answer.

Comment: here is what you can do [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845030/bind-to-a-value-defined-in-the-settings)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it,with  using System.Configuration

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["inactivity_interval"];
```

will return value.

[for more check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189364/reading-settings-from-app-config-or-web-config-in-net)

Answer (score 1):

In your app.config define  like below:

```
<applicationSettings>
  <MyApplication.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="inactivity_interval" serializeAs="String">
        <value>16</value>
      </setting>
    <MyApplication.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
```

Then in your xaml file refer namespace :

```
xmlns:p="clr-namespace:MyApplication.Properties"
```

and invoke the config values like below:

```
Value="{Binding Source={x:Static p:Settings.Default}, Path=inactivity_interval}"
```

Comment: I tried this but it looks for the value in Settings.settings.  If I have resharper add the missing property it adds a C# property to Settings.Designer.cs. My, I'd forgotten how obtuse xaml/wpf is.

Answer (score 0):

In your **app.config** change your **appsetting** to

```
<applicationSettings>
    <WpfApplication1.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="inactivity_interval" serializeAs="String">
            <value>10</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="maximumHeightPopUp" serializeAs="String">
            <value>260</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="horizontalArrowsHeight" serializeAs="String">
            <value>35</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="modelsListHeight" serializeAs="String">
            <value>100</value>
        </setting>
    </WpfApplication1.Properties.Settings>
</applicationSettings>
```

Then in code-behind C# for retrive values:

```
string inc_interval = WpfApplication1.Properties.Settings.Default.inactivity_interval.ToString();
string maximumHeightPopUp = WpfApplication1.Properties.Settings.Default.maximumHeightPopUp.ToString();
string horizontalArrowsHeight = WpfApplication1.Properties.Settings.Default.horizontalArrowsHeight.ToString();
string modelsListHeight= WpfApplication1.Properties.Settings.Default.modelsListHeight.ToString();
```

Comment: not in code behind. i want to use it in the xaml itself

Comment: @User9898 Did you ever figure out how to embed it directly in the xaml itself?

Comment: @User9898 Have you found the way to accommodate this requirement. Can you please share if found?