# Synchronise UIControls with Settings

Tags: c#, wpf, generics, settings

First, i am basically a C++ Developer. I am used to write classes to automate everything by metaprogramming. Today i got the idea to automate the synchronisation from the Settings with the UIElements.

**Question 1:** Does a similar project already exists?

If not: I dont search finished solutions, i need **ideas** and **hints** how to solve my task or **keep me away from bad ideas**.

At first i want to Synchronise:

- `TextBox` <-> `string`
- `Checkbox` <-> `bool`

**My proposels**:

1. Using extensions:

   ```
   public static class TextBoxSynchroniseExtension
   {
       public static string load(this TextBox control, string propertyName)
       {
           string value = Properties.Settings.Default[propertyName].ToString();
           control.Text = value;
           return value;
       }
       public static string save(this TextBox control, string propertyName)
       {
           string value = control.Text;
           Properties.Settings.Default[propertyName] = value;
           return value;
       }
   }
   ```

   Disadvantages:

   - I need to give the property name everytime.
   - For more UIElements i have to write a new extension.
2. Override the UIElements:

   (Untested)

   ```
   public partial class SyncSettingsTextBox : TextBox
   {
       [Description("The name for synchronise with the settings."), Category("Data")]
       public string SettingsName{ get; set; }

       public SyncSettingsTextBox(string settingsName) : base()
       {
           this.SettingsName = settingsName;
           LoadFromSettings();
       }

       public void LoadFromSettings()
       {
           this.Text = Properties.Settings.Default[SettingsName].ToString();
       }
       public void saveToSettings()
       {
           Properties.Settings.Default[SettingsName] = this.Text;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Creating a generic `UserControl` which re-/store his child by passing the propertyname and the settings name.

   Pseudocode:

   ```
   <StackPanel>
       <SynchroniseWrapper SettingsName="Name" PropertyName="Text" >
           <TextBox Text="I get overrided from Properties.Settings.Default.Name" />
       </SynchroniseWrapper>
       <SynchroniseWrapper SettingsName="PWD" PropertyName="Password" >
           <PasswordBox />
       </SynchroniseWrapper>
       <SynchroniseWrapper SettingsName="AutoLogin" PropertyName="IsChecked" >
           <CheckBox IsChecked="False" Content="Remember me?" />
       </SynchroniseWrapper>
   </StackPanel
   ```

**Question 2:** Which keywords i have to lookup for creating such `UserControls`.

Comment: The marked answer seems not to help me, because the `ItemSource` Property exists only for [IEnumerable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). An other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/846297/5064526) works, but I need to understand how it works. I dont want to save the settings instantly, only if some criterias are succuessfull.

Comment: why would you bind ItemsSource? Bind TextBox.Text and CheckBox.IsChecked to a string and a bool properties

Comment: Okay, I played something with it and figured out how it works. Thanks!