# Why a key is needed only for binding?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, app-config

I'm trying to bind via xaml an app.config value to a control. Here's the code:

```
//App.config:
<appSettings>
    <add key="SoundFile" value="C:\\Windows\\Media\\Windows Hardware Fail.wav"/>
</appSettings>

//window.xaml
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
xmlns:properties="clr-namespace:MfClient.Properties">
...
<SoundPlayerAction Source="{Binding Source={x:Static p:Settings.Default},Path=SoundFile}"/>
```

This gives this error:

> Error 44  Unknown build error, 'Key cannot be null. Parameter name: key
>   Line 30 Position 56.'

If I remove the binding everything turns out to be ok:

```
<SoundPlayerAction Source="C:\Windows\Media\Windows Hardware Fail.wav" />
```

In order to bind (w/o the two way approach that I don't need), I've followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154533/best-way-to-bind-wpf-properties-to-applicationsettings-in-c) and [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/patrickdanino/archive/2008/07/23/user-settings-in-wpf.aspx) other threads.

What am I getting wrong?

Comment: please elaborate more...where you setting alias for app.config ?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't explain myself. I was trying to keed the path of the sound in the app.config, in order to beeng able to change it after deploy.

Comment: You declare namespace prefix as `properties` and use it as `p:`. Is it  copy/paste error or your code actually looks like this?

Comment: It was a copypaste error directly in my code. Now it works! Sorry if I wasted your time.
The real problem beside my distraction was the misleading error description I think.

Answer (score 0):

You should bind your SoundplayerAction to a ViewModel or an AppconfigProvider class you created.  On that class create a Readonly property that retrieves the appconfig value.

You can add that class as a statis resource on your view.

This way you can also always easily change the location where you will get that path and combine multiple application settings into one provider class