# Save Windows Form Size

Tags: windows, vb.net, winforms, preferences, savestate

I'm developing a piece in VB.NET.  Inside my primary form, I'm creating a new form to use as a dialog.  I was wondering if there was a way to, upon the close of the new dialog, save it's size settings for each user (probably in a file on their machine, through XML or something?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can save it to the settings file, and update it on the 'onclosing' event.

to make a setting goto Project Properties ->settings -> then make a setting like 'dialogsize' of type system.drawing.size.

then do this in your dialog form:

```
Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
End Sub

Public Sub New(ByVal userSize As Size)
    InitializeComponent()
    Me.Size = userSize
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnClosing(ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs)
    MyBase.OnClosing(e)
    My.Settings.DialogSize = Me.Size
    My.Settings.Save()
End Sub
```

do something like this to check and use the setting:

```
    Dim dlg As MyDialogWindow
    If My.Settings.DialogSize.IsEmpty Then
        dlg = New MyDialogWindow()
    Else
        dlg = New MyDialogWindow(My.Settings.DialogSize)
    End If
    dlg.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: In the designer for my WinForm, I go under Properties and I see (PropertyBinding), but there is no DialogSize property that I can find.  Is this something you set up manually in code or in the designer?

Comment: DialogSize is a global Var that you need to make in the settings file.

Goto Project->'you project name' properties - > Settings tab-> add a setting called "DialogSize" or what ever you like of type System.Drawing.Size

Unfortunatly size is not in the propertybinding bit

Comment: Ok - I figured out what you were talking about and got it set up, but now when I try to invoke it, I get a ConfigurationErrorsException, saying that the Cofniguration system failed to initialize.  How do I go about resolving this?

Answer (score 2):

Although [this is for C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18421/best-way-to-bind-windows-forms-properties-to-applicationsettings-in-c), it will help with VB.Net as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can also add a new setting  to your application (size) and set it to `system.drawing.size`

Then, you make sure you save the current size to settings on close.

```
    Private Sub myForm_FormClosing(ByVal sender As System.Object,
                          ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) _
                             Handles MyBase.FormClosing

    My.Settings.size = Me.Size
    My.Settings.Save()

End Sub
```

and on load  you apply the size   you have saved  in settings

```
    Private Sub myForm_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
    Handles MyBase.Load
    ' if  this is the first  time to load the form 
    ' dont set the size ( the form will load  with the size  in the designe)
    If Not My.Settings.size.IsEmpty Then
        Me.Size = My.Settings.size
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that [I found online](http://christ-offer.blogspot.com/2012/02/vbnet-remember-application-window-size.html) that seems to work rather well for me.

Some of the previously mentioned solutions weren't working for me as expected. Depending on where my form was positioned at the time of closing the form wouldn't get repositioned back to that exact location when I would load it again.

This solution seems to do the trick by taking into account some other factors as well:

You need to set up these two setting under Project Properties -> settings: WindowLocation and WindowSize like so:

[image]

Then create the following function:

```
Private Sub LoadWindowPosition()

    'Get window location/position from settings
    Dim ptLocation As System.Drawing.Point = My.Settings.WindowLocation

    'Exit if it has not been set (X = Y = -1)
    If (ptLocation.X = -1) And (ptLocation.Y = -1) Then
        Return
    End If

    'Verify the window position is visible on at least one of our screens
    Dim bLocationVisible As Boolean = False

    For Each S As Screen In Screen.AllScreens
        If S.Bounds.Contains(ptLocation) Then
            bLocationVisible = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    'Exit if window location is not visible on any screen 
    If Not bLocationVisible Then
        Return
    End If

    'Set Window Size, Location
    Me.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
    Me.Location = ptLocation
    Me.Size = My.Settings.WindowSize
End Sub
```

Next, you'll need to add code to your form's load and closing events like so:

```
Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    LoadWindowPosition()
End Sub

Private Sub frmMain_Closing(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles Me.Closing
    My.Settings.WindowLocation = Me.Location
    My.Settings.WindowSize = Me.Size
End Sub
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this using the UI provided by the VB.NET IDE itself. In the properties pane for a form, look under the item called "(Application Settings)" and then under "Property Binding." You can bind just about every property of the form (including size and location) to a settings value for that application.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I found a way to do this using the `System.IO.IsolatedStorage`

Comment: Interesting - why did you choose IsolatedStorage?